# WebAudio scheduling non-AudioParam events

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, synthesizer

There are many AudioParams whose value can be set with `setValueAtTime` or `linearRampToValueAtTime`, usually limited to `gain` or `frequency` values. However this doesn't seem to work for changing an oscillator's waveform ("type"), or changing an Audio Buffer node's sample data.

Is there another way to schedule event changes to an oscillator's `type` (sawtooth, sine etc.) and a buffer's sample data against the WebAudio timer?

And what about the `start`/`stop` methods of `OscillatorNode` and `AudioBufferSourceNode`? Those seem to be only createable once:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'start' on 'AudioBufferSourceNode': cannot call start more than once.

So for example, trying to trigger a drum sound to playback multiple times isn't straight forward.

For context, I'm trying to build a synthetic music player, which plays and loops a sequence of notes using OscillatorNode and BufferNode as sound sources.

Comment: `setTimeout` maybe? But why don't you just create new nodes? Simply set a `node.stop(time)` and `node.onended = startANewNode`

Comment: `setTimeout/setInterval` could potentially work to control `node.start/stop`, but the timer isn't very reliable. Tons of stuttering issues or slowdown when tab is inactive. It all runs on the main thread, so it's pretty horrible for audio processing.

Answer (score 0):

for an oscillator you can't schedule a change to the type.  The only way to do that is to create a new oscillator of the correct type and start that at the desired time.  You have to be stop the old oscillator, of course.

The answer is pretty much the same for an AudioBufferSource.  Create a new one with the new sample data and `start()` it at the right time.